# How do I get TimeSpan in minutes given two Dates?

Tags: c#

To get TimeSpan in minutes from given two Dates I am doing the following

```
int totalMinutes = 0;
TimeSpan outresult = end.Subtract(start);
totalMinutes = totalMinutes + ((end.Subtract(start).Days) * 24 * 60) + ((end.Subtract(start).Hours) * 60) +(end.Subtract(start).Minutes);
return totalMinutes;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
TimeSpan span = end-start;
double totalMinutes = span.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 22):

Why not just doing it this way?

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2009, 6, 1);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
double totalminutes = (dt2 - dt1).TotalMinutes;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

I would do it like this:

```
int totalMinutes = (int)(end - start).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Really old but `cast` will truncate. Use `Convert.ToInt32` to get correct rounding.

Answer (score 9):

```
double totalMinutes = (end-start).TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 7):

See [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx):

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional minutes.