# How to convert timespan to datetime

Tags: c#, datepicker

I have 3 datepickers that are on time formats:
Time From, Time To and Duration.

First I need to get the difference of Time From and Time to and display it to the Duration DatePicker.

```
        DateTime fromTime = dtFrom.Value;
        DateTime toTime = dtTo.Value;

        TimeSpan duration = toTime.Subtract(fromTime)

        dtNoOfHours.Value = duration;
```

But I am having an error of: **System.InvalidCastException**

How to convert timespan to datetime?

Comment: `Timespan` is a duration, you need reference time to add or subtract timespan.

Comment: if duration is more than `1` day how you are going to show in a datepicker?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the ticks? Something like this: `dtNoOfHours.Value = new DateTime(duration.Ticks)`

Comment: @un-lucky it should not exceed 24 hours.

Comment: what kind of application is this?

Comment: posisble duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030869/how-do-i-get-timespan-in-minutes-given-two-dates

Comment: @un-lucky C# application

Comment: @Jonathan I think we are on different scenarion here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need (A DateTime with dummy date components):

```
DateTime Temp = new DateTime(2000, 12, 12, duration.Hours, 0, 0);

dtNoOfHours.Value  = Temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that **dtNoOfHours** stores the total duration in hours, I consider it must be **int**, so you could to code something like this:

```
dtNoOfHours.Value = duration.TotalHours;
```

However, if **dtNoOfHours** must be DateTime, I think you could use a third dummy datetime (maybe current datetime), in order to do something like the sample shown in the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx