# How to Count the schedule time have passed between 2 date time using VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi is there anyone who have idea how to count the Time passed between two date time.

example :

how many #07:00 AM# had passed between #06/25/2017 11:00 PM# and #06/29/2017 05:00 AM# 
from

> 06/25/2017 11:00 PM
>   06/26/2017 07:00 AM = +1
>   06/26/2017 11:00 PM
>   06/27/2017 07:00 AM = +1
>   06/27/2017 11:00 PM
>   and so on .....

This is about a Parking System Overnight Charging Rules. if a Parker enter the Parking area before 11:00 PM and exit 7:00 AM next day on wards the Parker will be charge of Overnight fee. what if the Parker stay for 4 days i need to count the number of 7:00 AM between the Entry Time and Exit Time.

Hope some one has experience this type of function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get TimeSpan in minutes given two Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030869/how-do-i-get-timespan-in-minutes-given-two-dates)

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You are expected to show some effort resolving your own problem

Comment: Hi sir Plutonix Thank you for editing my post this is my first time posting. thank you again for the tips and god bless.

Comment: @gserg I don't think it is a duplicate of that question...

Comment: Hi CodingYoshi that is correct. my question is not the same. thank you.

Comment: You can count the number of days between the start and end date by subtracting the two date times : (endDate - startDate).Days().  Then test 4 conditions 1) start and end before 7:00AM, no correction. 2) start after 7:00AM and end before 7:00AM, subtract one 3) start before 7:00 AM and end after 7:00 AM, add one 4) start and end after 7:00AM, no correction.

Comment: Hi jdweng Thank you for the idea i will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out if the datetiem you are starting with is on or before the 7th hour and the same for the last datetime but on or after the 7th hour. Then exclude these days and find the number of days in between. The days in between these dates, would for sure have a 7am so we will count them and then add the first and last (if they had 7 ams in them).

This is a simple approach and it is easy to understand but this is not the only approach.

```
var dayStart = DateTime.Parse("06/25/2017 11:00 PM");
bool addOneForFirstDay = false;
if (dayStart.Hour <= 7)
{
    addOneForFirstDay = true;
}

var dayLast = DateTime.Parse("06/29/2017 05:00 AM");
bool addOneForLastDay = false;
if (dayLast.Hour >= 7)
{
    addOneForLastDay = true;
}

// Skip the first day and skip the last day         
var numberOf7Ams = Convert.ToInt32(dayLast.Date.AddMinutes(-1).Subtract(dayStart.AddDays(1).Date).TotalDays);
if (addOneForFirstDay)
{
    numberOf7Ams += 1;
}

if (addOneForLastDay)
{
    numberOf7Ams += 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir Coding Yoshi this is the Perfect idea i will make the function and post it immediately. Thank you God Bless.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Sir CodingYoshi ====>> Thank you so much.. how can i mark this as Solve?

```
Public Structure OVERNIGHT_CONFIG
    Public AMOUNT As Double
    Public StartTime As Date
    Public GracePeriod As Long
    Public TimeIN As Date
    Public TimeOut As Date
    Public Is24 As Boolean
End Structure

Public Structure OVERNIGHT_RESULT
    Public OVERNIGHT_COUNT As Integer
    Public DAYS_COUNT As Integer
    Public AMOUNT As Double
End Structure

Public Shared Function GET_OVERNIGHT(ByVal O As OVERNIGHT_CONFIG) As OVERNIGHT_RESULT
    Dim ax As Date = O.TimeIN
    Dim bx As Date = O.TimeOut
    Dim R As New OVERNIGHT_RESULT
    If O.Is24 = True Then
        Dim d As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, O.TimeIN, O.TimeOut)
        R.DAYS_COUNT = d
        R.OVERNIGHT_COUNT = d
        R.AMOUNT = O.AMOUNT * d
        Return R
    End If
    R.DAYS_COUNT = 0
    R.AMOUNT = 0
    R.OVERNIGHT_COUNT = 0
    If ax.Date = bx.Date Then Return R
    Dim StartTime As Date = CDate(ax.Date & " " & O.StartTime)
    Dim EndTime As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, O.GracePeriod, StartTime)
    Dim Res As Integer = DateTime.Compare(ax, StartTime)
    If Res = 1 Then Return R
    Res = DateTime.Compare(bx, EndTime)
    If Res = -1 Then Return R

    'Code Block (c)2017 CodingYoshi === StockOverFlow ======>>>>>'
    Dim dayStart = DateTime.Parse(ax)
    Dim dayLast = DateTime.Parse(bx)
    Dim addOneForLastDay As Boolean = False

    Dim DL As Integer = dayLast.Hour & dayLast.Minute
    Dim ET As Integer = EndTime.Hour & EndTime.Minute
    If DL >= ET Then
        addOneForLastDay = True
    End If
    Dim ExCount = Convert.ToInt32(dayLast.[Date].AddMinutes(-1).Subtract(dayStart.AddDays(1).[Date]).TotalDays)
    If addOneForLastDay Then
        ExCount += 1
    End If
    '====== End ============================================>>>>'
    With R
        .OVERNIGHT_COUNT = ExCount
        .AMOUNT += O.AMOUNT * ExCount
    End With
    Return R
End Function
```

How to Use It

```
Dim r As New OVERNIGHT_RESULT
Dim o As New OVERNIGHT_CONFIG
With o
      .AMOUNT = 100
      .StartTime = "11:59:59 PM"
      .GracePeriod = 7
      .Is24 = False
      .TimeIN = DateTimePicker1.Value
      .TimeOut = DateTimePicker2.Value
End With
    r = GET_OVERNIGHT(o)
    MsgBox(r.AMOUNT & " " & r.DAYS_COUNT & " " & r.OVERNIGHT_COUNT)
```